# docker networking direct access to container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I try to migrate from multiple VM with static ip to container based solution.

Now I'm using VM with static ip:

[image]

I can ping and telnet my VMs `telnet 10.48.0.10 5432` and `telnet 10.48.0.11 5432`

I want to create a single docker host that allows me to do the same :

[image]

It would be great if I can `telnet 172.17.0.2 5432` and `telnet 172.17.0.3 5432`

I try to do it via docker because I want to manage the configuration.

**What would be the proper way to do this ?
Should I use a TCP Proxy inside a container to manage this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple.

create a network and bind it to the host

```
docker network create --subnet=10.0.0.0/24 -o "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="0.0.0.0" mynet
```

then run a container on `mynet` network

```
docker run -ti --net=mynet --ip=10.0.0.30 busybox
```

Now from another computer if you add route to your docker host (192.168.2.156) for this subnet :

```
sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.156
```

You can ping your container (`ping 10.0.0.30`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the containers from your host or from any other server that can get your host, you will need to map each container to a different port in the host server.

```
docker run -d -p 54321:5432 my_app
docker run -d -p 54322:5432 my_app
```

So you will can `telnet 10.200.0.1 54321` and `telnet 10.200.0.1 54322`